# Getting Invalid Xpath Error while using getAttribute method in Selenium

Tags: xpath, selenium

I am getting invalid xpath error while using getAttribute method... though I am able to locate the image using same xpath in firepath.

I am using below method..

String imgAtt = StartServer.browser.getAttribute("//img[contains(@alt,'Selenium IDE Logo')]");

**Error:**

Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Invalid xpath [2]: //img[contains(
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.throwAssertionFailureExceptionOrError(HttpCommandProcessor.java:112)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use `fn:contains`:

```
String imgAtt = StartServer.browser.getAttribute("//img[fn:contains(@alt,'Selenium IDE Logo')]");
```

Or declare the default function namespace. But I'm not familiar enough with Selenium to tell you how to do that.

Also the XPath you call in `getAttribute` will not return an attribute. It will be an `<img>` element. It's possible that function is throwing an exception due to the invalid parameter type. If you want just the attribute, use:

```
String imgAtt = StartServer.browser.getAttribute("//img/@alt[contains(.,'Selenium IDE Logo')]");
```